# Post photos to wall issue

Tags: facebook, post, photo

I can login to Facebook within my application and can also retrieve the information of the Facebook account of my application users.

However, when I post a photo to my users' Facebook wall, it always return NULL. Why?

Comment: you will need to post some code so that we can debug and help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prompt the user for `publish_stream` extended permission.  Facebook has a [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) that walks you through this step by step.